# git merging our changes into significant code upgrade

Tags: git, merge

I'm tracking a remote repo code base, and make small but significant changes locally to customise the code for our needs. So, the remote code is on branch 1.3.0 for example, and we create 1.3.0-custom to store our local modifications. I can then `git pull origin 1.3.0` to get the latest fixes.

Now the remote repo has been upgraded to a new branch - 1.3.1 - and this is a significant change. It's not practical to pull that into 1.3.0 - lots of merge conflicts, so the best approach would be to just start a new local branch tracking origin/1.3.1.

My question is this: is there a way to bring the changes *we* made in 1.3.0-custom into this new branch? I obviously don't want to 'revert' any of *their* changes back to 1.3.0, or we'll lose all the upgrades / fixes. But I do want to keep our local changes. Do I have to just do this the long way (e.g. get all the diffs between 1.3.0 and 1.3.0-custom, and apply them one by one in a new 1.3.1-custom branch)? Or is there some git-fu which can help here?

Example:

We pull 1.3.0 from the remote repo, then create our customised branch with `git checkout -b 1.3.0-custom`. We then edit and commit changes to a .css file for example.

Every day, the original 1.3.0 code base is updated with fixes and other new features, which we get by doing:

```
git checkout -b mergetest
git pull origin 1.3.0  # at this point, resolve any merge conflicts
git checkout 1.3.0-custom
git merge mergetest
git branch -d mergetest
```

I'm sure creating a branch just to do the merge / resolve isn't necessary, but I often get interrupted, and so if I lose track of where I'm up to in resolving any conflicts, I can just remove the `mergetest` branch and start again easily.

Now we have a completely different starting branch - 1.3.1 - and want some way to retrieve the edits *we* made to, e.g. that css file in the 1.3.0-custom branch, but *not* all the remote updates which we pulled into 1.3.0-custom.

I'm beginning to wonder if we can extract commits by author here, but I have a feeling our approach above puts some of the remote updates in as local commits because of the use of the temporary `mergetest` branch. Another complication is that the css file we edited in 1.3.0 might look very different in the 1.3.1 branch, so I'm guessing we'll need a diff anyway to avoid undoing any of the remote changes to that file.

Comment: [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) or [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) might be your friends here

Comment: Thanks - had a cursory look, but they both seem to assume the branches are related (especially rebase?). However, I _think_ 1.3.0 and 1.3.1 are completely separate branches with no common ancestor. I'll keep trying with cherry pick.

Comment: Could you provide an example how the history looks? I have a hard time figuring it out from your description and it would make it easier to tailer an answer to your specific needs.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're after here, but I'll try and edit the question with more detail. If there are specific git commands you'd like the output from, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since your custom branch contains *merge commits* I would suggest [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) for the task.

`cherry-pick` tries to take all changes introduced by a commit and apply them to the current *HEAD*. It effectivly duplicates the commit.

---

As a first step you should *checkout* a new branch, which points at the `1.3.1` branch.

```
git checkout -b 1.3.1-custom 1.3.1
```

Now we want to apply all changes of the `1.3.0-custom` branch on `1.3.1-custom`. How do we get a list of those commits?
This is a fairly straight forward use-case of the *double-dot* notation - take a look at the corresponding [chapter in the pro git book](http://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges) for better understanding.

Sadly `git cherry-pick` isn't very good at handling *merge commits*, especially when you try to apply a range of commits. Due to this we have to remove the *merge commits* from the range.

`git rev-list --no-merges 1.3.1..1.3.0-custom` will return a list of the *SHA-1* keys of all commits which you can find on `1.3.0-custom` but not on `1.3.1`.

Now we pass this list to `cherry-pick` using the `--stdin` option.

```
git rev-list --no-merges 1.3.1..1.3.0-custom | git cherry-pick --stdin
```

Since you said that `1.3.1` introduced a lot of changes, this will probably lead to some merge conflicts. If a conflict occures, git will give you the opportunity to resolve them and tell you to continue the process using `git cherry-pick --continue`.

If you want to squash all changes from `1.3.0-custom` into a single commit on `1.3.1-custom`, you can use the `-n` (`--no-commit`) option of `cherry-pick`.
Git will try to apply all changes in your working directory. You then can commit those changes as usual.